# Acumatica Default LocationID returns negative value

Tags: c#, acumatica

When trying to upgrade a customization package to 2021 R2 (Build 21.206.0024) I am getting a strange value for the Customer's Default Location ID.

Although I did not write this code, I am informed it was working in a previous version.

This happens when I add a new Customer in AR303000. My Client wants the Tax Zone to be determined by where the work is being done, as opposed to the customer's billing address' tax zone.

So, the code looks up the default location to use it to determine what tax zone is in effect.

This code is in the Persist() over ride:

```
   public void Persist(Action persistAction)
    {
       //Check for correct locationID before persisting PO Order to database
        var cachedLocation = Base.GetExtension<CustomerMaint.DefLocationExt>();
        var loc = cachedLocation.DefLocation.Current;

        var LocIDFirst = loc.LocationID;

        var dbLocation =
            SelectFrom<Location>.Where<Location.locationID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>
            .View.ReadOnly.Select(Base, loc.LocationID).TopFirst;
```

var dbLocation is null, because the value being returned from CustomerMaint.DefLocationExt is always a negative number.

For example:

[image: Runtime Screenshot]

Clearly the negative number is not correct. How can I get the right LocationID? Has this changed from a previous version?

Comment: This looks like an expected behavior for IDs. ID is generated when the record is actually saved to the database. Not sure what this code does, but I would assume you should use the current or cached inserted/updated records of the DataViews instead of trying to do a separate PXSelect there.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov -- you are right in that this code is in the wrong place. But my main question was: Why was LocationID a negative number. I think that is because it is a new customer and not yet saved.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it is negative because the record is not saved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the question of "Why is LocationID a negative number, and what to do about it?" -- I think the answer is the number is basically showing an error condition.

Once I trapped the null error message, and let the program continue around it, the message became more correct. It said:

[image: Error Message]

[image: No Tax Location]

And specifically showed that the TAX Zone was empty, which is not allowed. This is, as Samvel Petrosov pointed out in his comment, correct behavior.

FWIW, I think the number being returned was negative becasuse of this.
The `int?` value I was getting was: `-2147483647` When I Convert it to a Binary using:
string binary = Convert.ToString(locLong, 2);

I get:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
10000000000000000000000000000001
```

That looks to me an error message that got AND'd which makes it look like the signed bit was flipped. But I am not sure. It would be cool if someone from Acumatica actually could say why it gets set to this value.

But I am pretty sure it only shows like this because it is an error value (no LocationID is set, so it is put in an error value).